# How to make mouseenter and mouseleave events work in harmony?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mouseevent

I have a website and I need when the user hovers the mouse over stars to show a popover and when the mouse leaves to hide that popover.

I am using jquery to do that like the followings:

```
  $('.stars-rating-overview').mouseenter(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#starRatingStats").show();
    }, 300);
   }).mouseleave(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#starRatingStats").hide();
    }, 300);
   });
```

The problem I have with the above code is sometimes popover shows and does not disappear as if the mouseleave didn't trigger.

Could you please guide me to how I can make those two events work in harmony so that the popover does not show immediately when the user hovers over stars accidentally and to handle the case where the popover left shown after the mouse leaves stars?

Comment: Could you add JsFiddle or something like this?

Answer (score 2):

i suggest you to clear timeout, before beginning another:

```
  var ts = 0, th =0;
  $('.stars-rating-overview').mouseenter(function () {
    clearTimeout(th);
    ts = setTimeout(function () {
        $("#starRatingStats").show();
    }, 300);
   }).mouseleave(function () {
    clearTimeout(ts);
    th=setTimeout(function () {
        $("#starRatingStats").hide();
    }, 300);
   });
```